# texmaker overwrites file that was externally modified

Tags: texmaker

I noticed that if I have a file open in texmaker and then change the file using a different program (or, e.g., the file is shared via Dropbox and someone else makes changes), then texmaker will automatically overwrite the new version with its latest copy.

In similar situations with an editor like vim, vim will detect that the file has changed and ask me if I want to keep the old copy from vim or reload with the new file. This is the kind of behavior I want from texmaker.

Can I make texmaker give me the choice of reloading with the new file instead of silently overwriting the new file with its old copy?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since TeXstudio is based on TeXmaker this solution **could** apply also.

You can see below the option to do what you want. Go to *Options* menu and then *Configure*.

Note the **Show advanced options** selected on the left bottom corner.

[image]

Comment: Great! In texmaker, I opened Options, then instead of "Adv. Editor" for texstudio, do "Editor". The box to check is "Check for external changes".  I did a quick test and this gives me the behavior I want!

Comment: @Stephen, nice! In my opinion, TeXstudio is much better, specially for auto completion.

Comment: Great! It was very troubling when using svn checkout or git pull. If do not pay attention, directly compiling the files will overwrite the updates.

Comment: @Sigur: This solution does not work for Networkdrives (sftp).

Answer (score 1):

You can change this is Texmaker settings. Go to Options >> Configure TeXmaker >> Editor >> Check the box "Check for external changes".

[image]